# Want to copy applicable rows if value is met (Google Sheets Script)

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy

I have a master tab with names and teams. I have a tab for each team. When I run the script, I want it to copy the names (Column A) to the Team 1 tab if the team (Column G) is Team 1, and so on for each team

```html
function principalupdate() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var principallist = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Principal List")
  var agentfull = principallist.getRange("A:A")
  var team = principallist.getRange("G2:G990")
var fullteamdetail = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Full Team Schedule Detail")
  var fullagentfull = fullteamdetail.getRange("A:A")
var softwaredetail = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Software")
  var softwareagentfull = softwaredetail.getRange("A:A")
var phonesdetail = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Phones")
  var phonesagentfull = phonesdetail.getRange("A:A")
var billingdetail = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Billing")
  var billingagentfull = billingdetail.getRange("A:A")
var paymentsdetail = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Payments")
  var paymentsagentfull = paymentsdetail.getRange("A:A")
var multidetail = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Multi")
  var multiagentfull = multidetail.getRange("A:A")
var tier2detail = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Tier 2")
  var tier2agentfull = tier2detail.getRange("A:A")
// Delete Existing Full Names
fullagentfull.clearContent()
softwareagentfull.clearContent()
phonesagentfull.clearContent()
billingagentfull.clearContent()
paymentsagentfull.clearContent()
multiagentfull.clearContent()
tier2agentfull.clearContent()

// Copy Current Full Names
if (team = "Software"){
    agentfull.copyTo((softwareagentfull), {contentsOnly:true})}

}
```

Comment: I am using the clear content to clear out old names when new ones are added to the Principal List

Answer (score 0):

```
function teams() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const msh = ss.getSheetByName('mtab');
  const msr = 2;//master tab data start row
  const mvs = msh.getRange(msr, 1, msh.getLastRow() - msr + 1, msh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  mvs.forEach(r => {
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName(r[6]);
    if(sh) {
      sh.appendRow([r[0]]);
    }
  })
}
```